# how to split a bam file to separate bams according to reads mapped to chromosome

Tags: nextflow

nextflow;

input is a bam file;
for chr in [1..22, X, Y], execute samtools $bam $chr;
output are 24 bams

I already created a process called splitbam;
it takes an id, a bam file, and chr id as input, execute samtools, and output ${id}.${chr}.bam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that reading from a file can be an I/O-bound operation. If multiple processes try to read from the same BAM file simultaneously, they may end up competing for the same resources. Usually, we would want to avoid this as much as possible. A better way would be to pass in all the regions and have a single worker process split the BAM. There's lots of ways to do this, and the best solution depends on what you want exactly. You could even use another parameter to select which chromosomes to split from each BAM. Assuming your BAM files are coordinate-sorted and indexed, you could try:

```
params.indexed_bams = './path/to/bams/*.bam{,.bai}'
params.chroms = 'chr{{1..22},X,Y}'
```

```
process splitBAM {

    tag { sample }

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(indexed_bam)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("*.bam")

    script:
    def bam = indexed_bam.first()

    """
    for chrom in ${params.chroms}
    do
        samtools view \\
            -o "${bam.baseName}.\${chrom}.bam" \\
            "${bam}" \\
            "\${chrom}"
    done
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    indexed_bams = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.indexed_bams )
    
    splitBAM( indexed_bams )

    splitBAM.out.view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf -ansi-log false
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [stupefied_marconi] DSL2 - revision: 1383b12928
[91/a7c661] Submitted process > splitBAM (C)
[ce/f579b6] Submitted process > splitBAM (B)
[68/2e62aa] Submitted process > splitBAM (A)
[C, [/path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr1.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr10.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr11.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr12.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr13.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr14.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr15.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr16.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr17.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr18.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr19.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr2.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr20.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr21.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr22.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr3.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr4.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr5.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr6.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr7.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr8.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chr9.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chrX.bam, /path/to/work/91/a7c66188f92fd66331fe235bd923e7/C.chrY.bam]]
[A, [/path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr1.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr10.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr11.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr12.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr13.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr14.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr15.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr16.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr17.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr18.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr19.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr2.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr20.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr21.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr22.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr3.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr4.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr5.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr6.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr7.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr8.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chr9.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chrX.bam, /path/to/work/68/2e62aaee65cfb4791fe3d3b530fc15/A.chrY.bam]]
[B, [/path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr1.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr10.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr11.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr12.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr13.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr14.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr15.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr16.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr17.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr18.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr19.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr2.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr20.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr21.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr22.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr3.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr4.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr5.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr6.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr7.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr8.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chr9.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chrX.bam, /path/to/work/ce/f579b6299acafeaf53a386bd5abd25/B.chrY.bam]]
```

---

---

You'll not usually want to do this, but for completeness, here's one way to split the BAM files using a list of regions or chromosome names in a file (one per line). It just uses the [`each`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-repeaters-each) input qualifier to repeat the execution for each region in the collection of regions:

```
params.indexed_bams = './path/to/bams/*.bam{,.bai}'
params.regions = './regions.list'
```

```
process splitBAM {

    tag { "${sample}, ${region}" }

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(indexed_bam)
    each region

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${bam.baseName}.${suffix}.bam")

    script:
    bam = indexed_bam.first()
    suffix = region.replaceAll(':', '-')

    """
    samtools view \\
        -o "${bam.baseName}.${suffix}.bam" \\
        "${bam}" \\
        "${region}"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    Channel
        .fromFilePairs( params.indexed_bams )
        .set { indexed_bams }

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.regions )
        .splitText() { it.trim() }
        .collect()
        .set { regions }

    splitBAM( indexed_bams, regions )

    splitBAM.out.view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [grave_mcnulty] DSL2 - revision: 33a7a22c3b
executor >  local (72)
[a1/2ee71d] process > splitBAM (C, chr12) [100%] 72 of 72 ✔
[A, /path/to/work/60/3bc1fdbe20235076c5af4493a62977/A.chr6.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/a0/4c16d0871aea79e57bf674a1f32949/A.chr3.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/8c/e509e5b9aeea580fbf5cdb46c0a437/A.chr8.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/db/f96b1dd7bf07b26107afa814d82734/A.chr5.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/c8/49d20ee82c6c23b1e33b6974ba4551/A.chr7.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/43/a604a70bbac2f901b5ec18ede98f91/A.chr4.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/70/5ec915a5ae34cc16438fc3406bd921/A.chr1.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/f5/68049cedf63567004985524086051d/A.chr2.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/4d/4dd4b99aae0b8b2babef02a43e72f4/A.chr13.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/ff/2d2135e427e1c6c8d512065ca55055/A.chr10.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/65/024bdd698ca9da7c4ff7a98901f294/A.chr9.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/a5/b61625c6286d5a8719b7071ccea024/A.chr11.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/81/312802de9d1e6fda74501ebbc0aaaf/A.chr14.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/96/1a3956318fa953c2f10b12faecab22/A.chr18.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/20/276ac5a68a6edea88da145ff18c616/A.chr12.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/de/6c4eb41cb84b2e41bae058dde608f5/A.chr20.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/f4/4cba375ea0ab6bea2193475e56c20b/A.chr21.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/7d/a8ccf0ad38c5bd4f32979997998f39/A.chr19.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/17/e8a8c3123d8ca6440b1255e3fab001/A.chr15.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/ab/ee4398ad8bfb947322b19f703fd036/A.chr22.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/54/66707f7e243d4c765acfb057f686fa/A.chrX.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/bf/7cf4b2b22f733b95004e09bcb17a24/A.chrY.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/3f/cd987b9656f6affbc25e1fd73383ba/A.chr16.bam]
[A, /path/to/work/6f/1b076c7fe87a2f1fd366067b2a71f6/A.chr17.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/a2/d821e1520c628ff6e7bf229986bc40/B.chr4.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/ef/a4522fba782d6ab785be1492d426c1/B.chr13.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/00/ed80767027319a5fa63c6c9954a156/B.chr6.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/5e/efc8b4a52067a93a3020a30719c164/B.chr1.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/00/3336b1853123aa3dcede250e5f4ab9/B.chr2.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/65/e19c9845313f23134caf7a96c6fd6d/B.chr3.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/33/63857490a462c3573a84d7f184ad0e/B.chr5.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/c5/7cd52e2378dc077849fb95b2d4c6a3/B.chr11.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/66/8f0b18f23e9a7b2fcf966b721eff81/B.chr14.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/6c/6425122de40c637907d3fc403d6bfb/B.chr7.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/83/96973f5b21fdba623415c2f28d6587/B.chr15.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/be/26fd9f8b591caee13687c6908c6484/B.chr18.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/8a/9d080d0565c2b2b0e8984bac3af281/B.chr10.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/6f/bef89622a976e6219218d548484a9e/B.chr9.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/ea/2e42a4188eb1c46a3c192e4e53e75b/B.chr8.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/0a/dfa6ab659a21c3fc85c86cd99a8535/B.chr12.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/79/9322435a6b125adc9edf2616d51334/B.chrY.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/bb/71d75443d17680959aebfb410aafcd/B.chr20.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/99/20374da262707f5ac49969d6a5b307/B.chr16.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/80/4aff0eba480ef85ed5e1ab0bf4a11b/B.chr19.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/a9/abdd5b73f237185c57c1a816a94d5b/B.chrX.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/38/7861f2efc4754da157336d3d967d95/B.chr22.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/7b/5d328513b7bf6d03a2dc558898ff12/B.chr17.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/b3/81ac227bafa5eb95093d10cfd6b550/C.chr1.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/52/1220d524cdf2689052cd6cd0fc85de/C.chr3.bam]
[B, /path/to/work/1d/ba60a1afde1ab4dd2c469c6ff12bf8/B.chr21.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/90/1d146f3fa4e62bafbf96000ff2e4d5/C.chr4.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/50/fe8e2b2bf7cfcc522b4b465a1e6103/C.chr5.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/03/546d76f47d359c7561a8deba0c8389/C.chr8.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/e6/19629fd4b206dfb9e5f9a6ef6da78d/C.chr6.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/b6/a1993d8ee8837ba70ed12daf21a418/C.chr2.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/d8/d1bfc3254ea2205ac2a3cc210674db/C.chr11.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/4b/ef5c546102d29442f13217392e9ef2/C.chr13.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/72/848ab4f83561983e2fa6d74969a78d/C.chr15.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/df/afc23ff7ec596c5d51691fa4b67c43/C.chr7.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/52/0f4bab67efa1b013b69a42f2c211f7/C.chr9.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/a4/ceb86ff5c6b091af4c2c963ce4fda9/C.chr19.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/e7/a8928450a870464a08c372a0a96fc3/C.chr10.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/98/f1b2ce8fd5d498e77209cbc13e2898/C.chr14.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/73/d0edcdd7d922fc5a80842779421f48/C.chr21.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/4e/27d1000ef50e2672638b43e5bf24e0/C.chr17.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/b0/183bfdb6bb2f3702d9e7208aaf268d/C.chr18.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/c3/658b0323b33e7e0d0ddd1e14277edb/C.chrY.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/d4/06cef9ebb33f887eaf487f60cb5431/C.chrX.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/67/634d6a2ad97626c2afd4bc0dfe8ee7/C.chr16.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/35/cb224aa30c1f7fa89cb0e9f725361c/C.chr22.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/93/ed9f77df92b1c697764c1eff796dba/C.chr20.bam]
[C, /path/to/work/a1/2ee71d49591ebb8e827dde9adc602c/C.chr12.bam]
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, learnt a lot. Could you show me how to simutaneously read the same bam and do the split? (just want to figure out

Comment: @CaiBian No worries at all, please see my edit above. Hopefully it is useful, thanks!